# What algorithm does Math.random use?

Tags: javascript, random, mersenne-twister

Since I've been studying Computer Science, whenever random numbers come up, it's always Mersenne Twister. There's never even a question, no alternative. Just, use Mersenne Twister.

So what does JavaScript's Math.random use? It seems like it ought to use Mersenne Twister, since it's apparently without peer, but I can't find any reference to whether it does or not.

Does anyone know what it relies on, and/or why it isn't MT, if that's the case?

Comment: Quantum computing offers algorithms that can generate more "natural" random numbers. [Theoretically]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's likely implementation specific. The [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) does not force any algorithm, so a Linux JavaScript implementation might very well use `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: I didn't know there were multiple implementations of JavaScript? I'm not very experienced with web development. I was under the impression all JavaScript was the same.

Comment: @Aerovistae, JavaScript conforms to a specification, and the specification does not explicitly state which algorithm should be used for random numbers. There are many implementations of the language, such as the [V8 engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) used by Chrome, or [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey) used by Firefox. Also, JavaScript is a general purpose language not limited to the browser, so it can and does run on the server side as well, with frameworks such as [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and even in database servers such as [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org).