# How does Math.random() work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

I recently figured out how to get a random number via google, and it got me thinking how does `Math.random()` work. So here I am I can not figure out how they did Math.random() unless they used a time like thing does anyone know how JavaScript's `Math.random()` works or an equivalent?

Comment: The way it works is not dictated by the specification. It's probably some sort of [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) in most runtimes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361466/what-algorithm-does-math-random-use

Comment: or see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
Note: the ECMA description states that the number can be generated randomly or pseudo randomly, and that can be different for different platforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding "randomness"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness)

Comment: [You're getting a random number via Google?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/how-to-get-a-random-number-from-google-omnisearch-textbox) Then you should post an answer there…

Comment: @Bergi  I mean, I googled how to make a random number between x and y not using google for the calculator.

Comment: I found the HowStuffWorks [article](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question697.htm) useful.

Answer (score 33):

Math.random() returns a Number value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy.

Here's V8's implementation:

```
uint32_t V8::Random() {

    // Random number generator using George Marsaglia's MWC algorithm.
    static uint32_t hi = 0;
    static uint32_t lo = 0;

    // Initialize seed using the system random(). If one of the seeds
    // should ever become zero again, or if random() returns zero, we
    // avoid getting stuck with zero bits in hi or lo by reinitializing
    // them on demand.
    if (hi == 0) hi = random();
    if (lo == 0) lo = random();

    // Mix the bits.
    hi = 36969 * (hi & 0xFFFF) + (hi >> 16);
    lo = 18273 * (lo & 0xFFFF) + (lo >> 16);
    return (hi << 16) + (lo & 0xFFFF);
}
```

Source: http://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/papers/general/Google_Chrome_3.0_Beta_Math.random_vulnerability.pdf

Here are a couple of related threads on StackOverflow:

- [Why is Google Chrome's Math.random number generator not *that* random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550796/why-is-google-chromes-math-random-number-generator-not-that-random)
- [How random is JavaScript's Math.random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062902/how-random-is-javascripts-math-random)

Comment: This is the old implementation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52191522/58961 for the most recent version.

Answer (score 11):

See: [There's Math.random(), and then there's Math.random()](https://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/12/theres-mathrandom-and-then-theres.html)

Until recently (up to version 4.9.40), V8’s choice of PRNG was MWC1616 (multiply with carry, combining two 16-bit parts). It uses 64 bits of internal state and looks roughly like this:

```
uint32_t state0 = 1;
uint32_t state1 = 2;
uint32_t mwc1616() {
  state0 = 18030 * (state0 & 0xffff) + (state0 >> 16);
  state1 = 30903 * (state1 & 0xffff) + (state1 >> 16);
  return state0 << 16 + (state1 & 0xffff);
```

The 32-bit value is then turned into a floating point number between 0 and 1 in agreement with the specification.

MWC1616 uses little memory and is pretty fast to compute, but unfortunately offers sub-par quality:

- The number of random values it can generate is limited to 232 as
  opposed to the 252 numbers between 0 and 1 that double precision
  floating point can represent.
- The more significant upper half of the
  result is almost entirely dependent on the value of state0. The
  period length would be at most 232, but instead of few large
  permutation cycles, there are many short ones. With a badly chosen
  initial state, the cycle length could be less than 40 million.
- It fails many statistical tests in the TestU01 suite.

This has been pointed out to us, and having understood the problem and after some research, we decided to reimplement Math.random based on an algorithm called xorshift128+. It uses 128 bits of internal state, has a period length of 2^128 - 1, and passes all tests from the TestU01 suite.

```
uint64_t state0 = 1;
uint64_t state1 = 2;
uint64_t xorshift128plus() {
  uint64_t s1 = state0;
  uint64_t s0 = state1;
  state0 = s0;
  s1 ^= s1 << 23;
  s1 ^= s1 >> 17;
  s1 ^= s0;
  s1 ^= s0 >> 26;
  state1 = s1;
  return state0 + state1;
}
```

The new implementation landed in V8 4.9.41.0 within a few days of us becoming aware of the issue. It will become available with Chrome 49. Both Firefox and Safari switched to xorshift128+ as well.

Answer (score 6):

It's correct that they use a "time like thing". A pseudo random generator is typically seeded using the system clock, because that is a good source of a number that isn't always the same.

Once the random generator is seeded with a number, it will generate a series of numbers that all depending on the initial value, but in such a way that they seem random.

A simple random generator (that was actually used in programming languages a while back) is to use a prime number in an algorithm like this:

```
rnd = (rnd * 7919 + 1) & 0xffff;
```

This will produce a series of numbers that jump back and forth, seemingly random. For example:

```
seed = 1337
36408
22089
7208
63833
14360
11881
41480
13689
6648
```

The random generator in Javascript is just a bit more complex (to give even better distribution) and uses larger numbers (as it has to produce a number that is about 60 bits instead of 16), but it follows the same basic principle.

Comment: can you provide a source?

Comment: I have no idea what the purpose of a seed is, and wouldn't that make subsequent values dependent on initial value / previous values?

Answer (score 1):

you may want this article for a reference: https://hackernoon.com/how-does-javascripts-math-random-generate-random-numbers-ef0de6a20131

And btw, recently I am also curious about this question and then read the source code of NodeJS. We can know one possible implementation from Google V8:

The main entry for the random (`MathRandom::RefillCache` function):
https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/math-random.cc

How the seed initialized? see also here: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/base/utils/random-number-generator.cc#L31

The key function is (`XorShift128`  function):
https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/base/utils/random-number-generator.h#L119

in this header file, there are references to some papers:

```
// See Marsaglia: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper
// And Vigna: http://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/xorshiftplus.pdf
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<script>

function generateRandom(){  //  Generate and return a random number
    var num = Math.random();
    num = (Math.round((num*10)))%10;
    return num;
}

function generateSum(){ //  Generate a problem
    document.getElementById("ans").focus();
    var num1 = generateRandom();
    var num2 = generateRandom();
    document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = num1;
    document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = num2;
    document.getElementById("pattern1").innerHTML = printPattern(num1);
    document.getElementById("pattern2").innerHTML = printPattern(num2);

}

function printPattern(num){ //  Generate the star pattern with 'num' number of stars
    var pattern = "";
    for(i=0; i<num; i++){
        if((i+1)%4 == 0){
            pattern = pattern+"*<br>";
        }
        else{
            pattern = pattern+"*";
        }
    }
    return pattern;
}

function checkAns(){    //  Check the answer and give the response
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML);
    var enteredAns = parseInt(document.getElementById("ans").value);
    if ((num1+num2) == enteredAns){
        document.getElementById("patternans").innerHTML = printPattern(enteredAns);
        document.getElementById("patternans").innerHTML += "<br>Correct";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("patternans").innerHTML += "Wrong";
        //remove + mark to remove the error

    }
}

function newSum(){
    generateSum();
    document.getElementById("patternans").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("ans").value = "";
}

</script>
```