# How does the Javascript device that generate any random number between two number inclusive work mathematically?

Tags: javascript, math

`Math.floor()` rounds the decimal to "A number representing the largest integer less than or equal to the specified number." So `Math.floor(45.03)` will be 45 and `Math.floor(-34.23)` will be 35.

And Math.random generates a (decimal, or whole) number between 0, inclusive and 1 exclusive.

I just learned this:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
```

This will generate a random whole number between max and min inclusive. I can figure out mathematically why it works. Just wondering.

Lets call `Math.random(), R; max M;min m.` If you just look at the inside:

```
 R*(M-m+1)+m //or RM-Rm+R+m,
```

It's obvious the quantity is at least as big as m. But why is it no bigger than M? I assume this works with negative M and m, as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Math.random() work in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109006/how-does-math-random-work-in-javascript)

Comment: @Antony No, not that.

Comment: So can you figure out mathematically why it works? Then what's the problem? Or you CAN'T figure out it?

Comment: This is really less of a programming problem and more something for one of the math sites: http://stackexchange.com/sites#science

Comment: There is a math tag so...

Comment: As that tags says: *Mathematics is behind all programming at some level, but math questions here should be specifically related to a programmed implementation.* Your question is purely about the mathematics, independent of any specific implementation.

Comment: it's the same as the standard function for interpolating between two values - `interp(v0, v1, x) = v0 + (v1 - v0) * x`, given x in range [0..1].  When x = 0, interp = v0, and when x = 1, interp = v0 + v1 - v0 = v1.  The only minor difference is that Math.random() is exclusive on the upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume r is `Math.random()` which is a number between 0, inclusive and 1 exclusive; which we show it as:

```
// Let r is shortcut for Math.random()
r => [0 to 1}  // lets [] symbols for inclusive and {} symbols for exclusive
```

to get a number in a larger scale, we can multiply it with N:

```
//scale by N:
r * N => [0 to N}
```

to include N in our range, we can use one number greater than N and round the result:

```
r * (N+1)        => [ 0 to (N+1) }
floor(r * (N+1)) => [ 0 to N ]     // decimals after N will be removed
```

So up to now, we reach a good formula: to have `a random number between 0 and N (both inclusive)`, we should use: `floor(r * (N+1))`

if we shift the equation to start from a `min` value:

```
//add `min` to equation:
floor(r * (N+1)) + min => [ min to N+min ]
```

it is almost finished: consider `N+min` as `max`, we have:

```
N+min = max  =>  N = max-min
```

replace it in our equation:

```
floor(r * (max-min+1)) + min => [ min to max ]
```

Note: It is obvious that we can move the min inside the floor function as it is an integer value and does not have any decimal digits. so we could write it also as:

```
floor( r * (max-min+1) + min )
```

Comment: Amazing!Really easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy, but you need to write it down a little wordy:

```
var min = 10;
var max = 20;
var difference = max - min; // 10
var random = Math.random() // (0...1)
var randomDifference = random * difference; // (0...difference)
var withMinOffset = randomDifference + min; // (10...20)
```

The above `withMinOffset` is the random value between min and max. The reason this works is because you know the number *cannot* be lower than min, so we will always have to add the min to the randomised number. Then we know we want a range, so we can use `max - min` to get the maximum amount of randomness we can get.

The number will never be bigger than M simply because `difference + min === max`, which is the upper limit. Multiplying say, 10, by a random number between 0 and 1 will always generate a number between 0 and 10. Adding the min to it will always have a number between min and min + difference.

Comment: You forgot to add one in the difference?

Comment: @user132522 I did not, the number will range between 10.00 to 20.00. i am unsure why you added it...

Comment: I don't know if your function really works, because I don't know how to test it yet.

Comment: @user132522 its not a function, its the process explained. The final line contains the number in range.

Comment: But this process will never get you 20, because Math.random() doesn't gives 1.

Comment: @user132522 I said _between_. It will also never give you 10. Whats the point of a random number if it conforms to that rule?