# JavaScript: Does Math.Random() use the current timestamp to generate random numbers?

Tags: javascript, random

Follow up, if I manage to send two requests at EXACTLY the same time, does Math.Random() generate the same number?

Comment: I doubt they use time, look at the source code for the engines.

Comment: I presume you are asking because you want to use it as some kind of security feature. Do not use `Math.random` for security related stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What algorithm does Math.random use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361466/what-algorithm-does-math-random-use)

Answer (score 3):

The spec for [`Math.Random()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.random):

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0
> but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately
> uniform distribution over that range, **using an implementation‑
> dependent algorithm or strategy**. This function takes no arguments.
>
> Each Math.random function created for distinct realms must produce a
> distinct sequence of values from successive calls.

In other words, how the randomness is implemented depends entirely on the JavaScript engine, or *browser*. It may or may not use the current time as part of its implementation.

Relevant resources:

- Here's [V8 JavaScript Engine's implementation](https://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/12/theres-mathrandom-and-then-theres.html) *(as of December 17, 2015)*
- Related thread on Stack Overflow: [How does Math.Random() work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109006/how-does-math-random-work-in-javascript)